# Swiftui: @environmentObject - Cannot use instance member within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swiftui, environmentobject

I try to pass data from an @environmentObject to a @State object in the TopLevel

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var countRecognizer: themeCounter
    @State var theme: themeModel = themeData[countRecognizer.themeCount]

    @State var hideBar = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            videoCard(theme: theme)
                .statusBar(hidden: true)

            Text("\(self.countRecognizer.themeCount)")

            if hideBar == true {

            }
        }
```

But  I am getting this error: "Cannot use instance member within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

the themeData Array should get the Int from the environment Object.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There is no `themeData` declaration in provided code - would you show how you pass it in? Is it global variable?

Comment: themeData is from an Array following the Class, called themeModel:

Comment: import SwiftUI


let themeData: [themeModel] = [
    
    
    themeModel(titleL1: "", titleL2: "", subHead: ""),

Answer (score 1):

do your

```
theme: themeModel = themeData[countRecognizer.themeCount]
```

in

```
.onAppear(...)
```

Comment: this won't fix the issue, as `themeModel` is non optional. It will work if you make `var theme: themeModel?`, but at that point you have to make a view that supports having `nil` as a `theme`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `countRecognizer` directly from the initial value of another property, and there is no easy fix.

I suggest you to look into refactoring your `@State var theme` property into a `@Published var theme` inside the `themeCounter` ObservableObject. Apple tutorials will help you: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/tutorials

As an aside: DON'T NAME TYPES WITH A LOWERCASE.

- `themeModel` should be `ThemeModel`
- `themeCounter` should be `ThemeCounter`
- `videoCard` should be `VideoCard`

Comment: Thanks, Mate. My main issue is to control the ThemeData input with a gesture. The environmentobject was an approach. 
If I put "var theme" inside the ThemeCounter as a published, how can I pass it to videoCard(theme: theme)?

Comment: `themeCounter.theme` ?